# How do you do a hierarchical chart of accounts using MySQL WITH RECURSIVE?

Tags: mysql, tree, mariadb, recursive-query, rollup

I am having trouble understanding the use of WITH RECURSIVE to implement common queries and reports using the adjacency model, where one record refers to its "super" record.

I have a number of InnoDB tables that have fields that are foreign keys into the same table.

For example, I implemented a double-entry accounting system with a 'general_journal' table holding (among others) `Amount`, `Source`, and `Destination` columns. The latter two columns reference an 'accounts' table using standard seven-digit account numbers that arrange in a hierarchy.

So the 'accounts' table would have (for example) a row with `ID` containing '1000000', `Super` containing NULL, and `Name` containing 'Assets.'

Then there's other rows like '1000010' (`ID`), '1000000' (`Super`), 'Cash Assets' (`Name`), and '1000011' (`ID`), '1000010' (`Super`), 'Chequing' (`Name`).

I'm stumped on how to create standard "Balance Sheet" and "Profit and Loss" reports for a standard financial statement, where the various sub-accounts would show their own sum (sum of the 'general journal' `Amount` columns with the same `Source` account, minus those with the same `Destination` account), and each super account would show a sum of all sub-account roll-ups that they contain.

Another example I'm stumped on… our not-for-profit co-op breeds animals. Each animal record has an `ID` and the fields `Dam` and `Sire` that contain the ID of that animal's mother and father, respectively. I can't figure out how this information can be represented as a "family tree" sort of report. Examples I've found don't seem to be easily changed to show a double-recursive situation.

I'm using MariaDB 10.2.13. I've poked around at it, and Googled for WITH RECURSIVE examples, but something is not getting through my thick head…

This is getting long, but I'm happy to add schemas and sample data, if that would help.

Thanks for any advice offered!

Comment: First 6 digits are a group?  Last digit is either super or child number??

Comment: @Rick James: The account numbers are actually rather arbitrary, and should not be used to show hierarchy. But each account row has an explicit `Super` column that is the `ID` of the containing account.

Comment: Then explain what is meant by "various sub-accounts".  In your example, are 1000010 and 1000011 "sub-accounts"?  Then `SELECT SUM(...) ... GROUP BY id` might be close to what you want?

Comment: That is indeed how I am rolling up accounts to date. But I need to further roll them up into their super accounts.

Comment: Please show us the query to do that rollup.